# PROPFIND fails with curl on Apache

Tags: git, apache, curl, propfind

I'm trying to setup a GIT server, authenticated through LDAP. I am using Apache. The GIT client fails when trying to push.

```
git push
```

According to the server logs, the problem is with WebDAV PROPFIND command, which is not authenticated by GIT and end up with a 401 http code:

Apache access.log:

```
192.168.23.199 - - [13/Jul/2017:13:39:27 +0000] "GET /test.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 381
192.168.23.199 - johndoe [13/Jul/2017:13:39:27 +0000] "GET /test.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 59
192.168.23.199 - johndoe [13/Jul/2017:13:39:27 +0000] "GET /test.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1" 200 23
192.168.23.199 - - [13/Jul/2017:13:39:27 +0000] "PROPFIND /test.git/ HTTP/1.1" 401 381
```

My config file contains a LimitExcept:

```
   <Location />
        Dav on

        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://server:3268 server:3268 server:3268 server:3268/dc=mydc,dc=local?sAMAccountName,distinguishedName,memberOf,displayName"

        AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=documentation,OU=Script-Users,OU=Orange,DC=qconsulting,DC=local"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "xxxxx"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "AD Authorization required"


        <LimitExcept PROPFIND>
            Require valid-user
        </LimitExcept>

        AllowOverride None

        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^pub/git$  /pub/git/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi
        RewriteRule ^pub/git/$  /pub/git/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi
        RewriteRule ^/(.*\.git/(?!/?(HEAD|info|objects|refs)).*)?$ /cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,PT]
     </Location>
```

The strange thing is that I tried to do PROPFIND request through curl and cadaver. And it fails with curl (401) and it succeeds with cadaver (207)

curl  --request PROPFIND http://server/test.git/

Apache Log:

```
192.168.23.199 - - [13/Jul/2017:11:11:46 +0000] "PROPFIND /test.git/ HTTP/1.1" 207 436
```

cadaver http://server/test.git/

propnames /

```
192.168.23.199 - - [13/Jul/2017:11:11:59 +0000] "PROPFIND /test.git/ HTTP/1.1" 401 381
```

Comment: There was [a bug in git](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/116#issuecomment-51979630) that was fixed in version 2.0.3. What version do you use?

Comment: I'm using GIT 1.8.3.1, it's the last available on RedHat 7. But there seems to be also a problem on Apache. I cannot get the Limit / LimitExcept to work for the PROPFIND method. It does seem to work for methods like GET / POST. I'm using Apache HTTPD 2.4.6.